# Coldfusion cfhttp - have a URL var that is breaking the get function

Tags: url, coldfusion, cfhttp

I am trying to perform a cfhttp post and I need to include a URL in the URL vars to give directions to where to deposit a delivery receipt.

Here is my code:

```
    <cfhttp result="CFHTTP" method="GET" url="http://xxxxxxxxxxx/send-sms.php?sender=#numbers.number#&to=#get_sms.receiver#&message=#get_sms.msgdata#&dlr-url=#get_sms.dlr_url#">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="sender" value="#numbers.number#">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="to" value="#get_sms.receiver#">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="message" value="#get_sms.msgdata#">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="dlr-url" value="#get_sms.dlr_url#">
</cfhttp>
```

And everything works if I do not include the dlr_url which is similar to the following:

http://entry.xxxxxxxx.com/process_dlr.cfm?status=%d&msisdn=%p&dlr-mask=31&data=%a&batchid=161F3CE3-E031-9CFF-7364A9C1AC50AA5B&destination=2&accountID=123&sub_id=123456789&carrierID=2222

I can only assume that items like "?" and "&" would be breaking the process. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thank you all for any help.

Answer (score 5):

There are some flaws here.

1. Don't specify query params manually in the `url` attribute. Use `<cfhttpparam param type="url"` instead.
2. A `GET` request does not support a body (form data), so `<cfhttpparam type="formfield"` is not going to do anything.
3. Why are you even trying to send the same params via query string AND body?

If you use the proper `cfhttpparam` tags, you don't have to encode the values manually.

## Proper request with params via query string

```
<cfhttp result="CFHTTP" method="GET" url="http://xxxxxxxxxxx/send-sms.php">
    <cfhttpparam type="url" name="sender"  value="#numbers.number#">
    <cfhttpparam type="url" name="to"      value="#get_sms.receiver#">
    <cfhttpparam type="url" name="message" value="#get_sms.msgdata#">
    <cfhttpparam type="url" name="dlr-url" value="#get_sms.dlr_url#">
</cfhttp>
```

## Proper request with params via query string AND body

```
<cfhttp result="CFHTTP" method="POST" url="http://xxxxxxxxxxx/send-sms.php">
    <cfhttpparam type="url"       name="sender"  value="#numbers.number#">
    <cfhttpparam type="url"       name="to"      value="#get_sms.receiver#">
    <cfhttpparam type="url"       name="message" value="#get_sms.msgdata#">
    <cfhttpparam type="url"       name="dlr-url" value="#get_sms.dlr_url#">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="sender"  value="#numbers.number#">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="to"      value="#get_sms.receiver#">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="message" value="#get_sms.msgdata#">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="dlr-url" value="#get_sms.dlr_url#">
</cfhttp>
```

The difference: `POST` allows query string **and** body payload. `GET` only allows query string.

I assume you are more familiar with PHP, so here's how the `type` attribute translates:

- `type="url"       name="sender"` => `$_GET['sender']`
- `type="formfield" name="sender"` => `$_POST['sender']`

Answer (score 0):

I don't what I was thinking....

Needed to encode: `#URLEncodedFormat(get_sms.dlr_url)#`

Sorry I didn't think of thanks!!!

Comment: Check my answer for a proper fix.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that makes sense. Appreciate your additional assistance.